# How do I make this subroutine able to work with doubles not just ints?

Tags: java

I have to make this subroutine able to work with doubles, not just ints. I'm new to coding and really dont get this.

Here is the subroutine:

```
public static int readNumber() throws Exception 
{
    int number = 0;
    char characterAsciiCode = '0';
    int numberValue = 0;
    characterAsciiCode = (char)System.in.read();
    while ( characterAsciiCode != '\n')
    {
        //convert the character code to an actual numeric value
        numberValue = characterAsciiCode - '0';
        //integrate the numeric digit into the total number
        number = number * 10 + numberValue;
        //get the next character from the keyboard buffer
        characterAsciiCode = (char)System.in.read();
    }        
    return number;
}
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can't you use Scanner? Like "Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); double n = s.nextDouble();"

Comment: I don't understand why someone who is new to coding would have to do this. It is really not a beginner-friendly problem, and if you just need to read numbers (ints *or* doubles) from user input, this is not a good way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

So assuming the idea was that you were supposed to be constructing the number yourself without nextInt() or nextDouble(), you could extend the logic you already have as follows:
1) if you encounter the new line before a ., just return the double of the number you found so far.
2) if you encounter the . (I am being Americentric here, if where yuou live the comma is used, adapt accordingly) first, save the number, accumulate the decimal part as an integer using the same routine as before (terminated by new line), but track the length of the decimal part.
3) return the number part plus the decimal part divided by 10^decimalLength.
Here's the code. It may have an unnecessary cast or two. I was being cautious.

```
public static double readNumber() throws Exception {
 int number = 0;
 char characterAsciiCode = '0';
 int numberValue = 0;

 characterAsciiCode = (char) System.in.read();

 while ((characterAsciiCode != '\n') && (characterAsciiCode != '.')) {
     //convert the character code to an actual numeric value
     numberValue = characterAsciiCode - '0';
     //integrate the numeric digit into the total number
     number = number * 10 + numberValue;
     //get the next character from the keyboard buffer
     characterAsciiCode = (char) System.in.read();
 }
 if (characterAsciiCode == '\n') {
     return (double) number;
 }
 int decimal = 0;
 int decimalLen = 0;
 characterAsciiCode = (char) System.in.read();
 while (characterAsciiCode != '\n') {
     //convert the character code to an actual numeric value
     numberValue = characterAsciiCode - '0';
     //integrate the numeric digit into the total number
     decimal = decimal * 10 + numberValue;
     decimalLen++;
     //get the next character from the keyboard buffer
     characterAsciiCode = (char) System.in.read();
 }
 return (double) number + (double) decimal / Math.pow(10, decimalLen);

 }
```